# How to run npm serve with https?

Tags: npm, https, vercel, npx, serve

I just had a index.html in my working directory, and typed `npx serve`.
I can access http://localhost:3000 but I want to host https://localhost:3000.

How to run 'serve' with https mode?
What option do I need?